# diffrence in working of post increment operator with and & or operator

Tags: c

This post-increment operator usage is confusing.

```
{int a=0,b=1,c=2,d;
d=a++||b++||c++
printf("%d %d %d %d",a,b,c,d);}
```

output is

> 1,2,2,1

value of `c` did not increase but if I replace it with `&&` operator it increases. Why?

Comment: @Olaf Sir, I respectfully disagree. This is not a dupe, atleast not of that one.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You might be right, I can have missread. It is not exactly clear which "and operator" OP means, though. Your edit implies the logical "and" and I tend to agree now, but we better had asked for clarification from OP first (you before editing, I before dup-voting). I'm sure there is another dup, but mine is wrong indeed here.

Comment: it is the logical "and"

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.14, (*emphasis mine*)

> Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to `0`, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.**

So, in your case,

```
 d=a++||b++||c++
```

is the same as

```
 d= ( (a++ || b++) || c++)
```

Then, the statement inside the first parenthesis is evaluated, first `a++` (post-increment) evaluates to 0 (side-effect pending), so the RHS of the first `||` is evaluated, `b++`, producing 1 and the result of the `||` operation is TRUE, yields 1.

That result, `1`, is the LHS of the second `||`. Hence, the RHS of the second `||` (`c++`) is not evaluated anymore and the final result becomes TRUE, again yielding `1`, which gets stored in `d`.

So, finally,

- `a++` is evaluated, becomes 1
- `b++` is evaluated, becomes 2
- `c++` is **not** evaluated, remains 2
- the result of `||` is stored in `d`, that is TRUE, so stores 1.

On the other hand, for logical AND `&&` operator,

> [...] If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

So, if you replace the last `||` with `&&`, then for the outer statement, the LHS becomes 1 and the RHS evaluates, making `c++` to be evaluated and incremented, as a side effect.

Comment: @Olaf but in this case, this is not UB. all are different variables.

Comment: but why this is not the case with and operator

Comment: @SanyaPandey: You effectively ask "how do the `||` and `&&` operators work". Please read the description of both operators. You will find that in every good C book or online by a simple search. Note that you are required to do at least _some_ effort on your own to find an answer.

Comment: one more thing the increment operator has higher precedence as compared to logical and operator. the increment is evaluated right to left.